# Is it possible to print a specific position value from each arrays in php?

Tags: php, arrays

I've some array in php. I want to print a specific value from a specific position of each array. For example, If i want to print the second value from each array, so that what's the function for that in php ?

```
$firstArray = array("Saif", "Website Development", "Senior");

$secondArray = array("Rifat", 25, "Mentor");

$thirdArray = array("Fahim", "Elder Brother", "PreCadet School");
```

Comment: I wonder if all responses are trolling or something. You don't need a function for that. Just use `echo $firstArray[1]`, for example.

Comment: @GinoPane `echo` is a function. Are you trolling?

Comment: @Andreas `echo` is a language construct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$firstArray = array("Saif", "Website Development", "Senior");
$secondArray = array("Rifat", 25, "Mentor");
$thirdArray = array("Fahim", "Elder Brother", "PreCadet School");

function printPosition($position)
{
    $arguments = func_get_args();
    array_shift($arguments);

    foreach($arguments as $argument) {
        $keys = array_keys($argument);
        if(isset($keys[$position])) {
            echo $argument[$keys[$position]] . '<br>' . PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}

printPosition(1, $firstArray, $secondArray, $thirdArray);
```

gives output:

```
Website Development<br>
25<br>
Elder Brother<br>
```

Worth to note that the solution also works when one or more array have non numeric keys.

for example with these arrays:

```
$firstArray = array("Saif", "second" => "Website Development", "Senior");
$secondArray = array("first" => "Rifat", 25, "Mentor");
$thirdArray = array("boo" => "Fahim", "moo" => "Elder Brother", "third" => "PreCadet School");
```

you still get the same result:

```
Website Development<br>
25<br>
Elder Brother<br>
```

Comment: I suggest you use array_shift instead of this skipp thing. See here, in my opinion a much cleaner code. https://3v4l.org/SvGeG

Answer (score 0):

Use array_column when you have added all arrays to one array.

```
$firstArray = array("Saif", "Website Development", "Senior");

$secondArray = array("Rifat", 25, "Mentor");

$thirdArray = array("Fahim", "Elder Brother", "PreCadet School");

$arr = [$firstArray, $secondArray, $thirdArray];

echo implode(", ", array_column($arr, 1));
```

This will echo the second column of the arrays with comma space as the delimiter.

https://3v4l.org/6Q1JQ

Answer (score 0):

You can approach this by using a custom `function` OR `array_column`

```
$firstArray = array("Saif", "Website Development", "Senior");
$secondArray = array("Rifat", 25, "Mentor");
$thirdArray = array("Fahim", "Elder Brother", "PreCadet School");
function getValuesByPosition($position, ...$arr){ //Splat operator
    $res=[];
    foreach($arr as $key => $value){
      $res[] = $value[$position];
    }
    return $res;
}
$result = getValuesByPosition(1,$firstArray,$secondArray,$thirdArray);
```

OR

Using `array_column` as @andreas solution.